# Always visible textview , invisible not working in android

Tags: android

Here is my code :

```
arrow.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        String user = user_name.getText().toString();
        String pass = pass_word.getText().toString();

        String check = db.getPassword(user);

        if(check.equals(pass))
        {
            user_name.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            pass_word.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            arrow.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            pg.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            for(int i=0;i<100000;i++)
            {
                pg.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

            Intent openQr_code = new Intent ("com.cinamon.vampskin.MENU_ADMIN");
            startActivity(openQr_code);

        }
        else
        {
            user_name.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            pass_word.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            arrow.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            pg.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            for(int j=0;j<100000;j++)
            {
                pg.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Invalid username or password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            user_name.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            pass_word.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            arrow.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            pg.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            noOfTimesLoginError++;

            if(noOfTimesLoginError == 3)
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Try again in 10 seconds...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                user_name.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                pass_word.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                arrow.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                pg.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                time_text.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                for(int time = 10 ; time>0 ; time--)
                {
                    for(int m = 0 ; m < 1000 ; m++)
                    {
                        time_text.setText("00 : 00 : "+time);
                    }
                }

                user_name.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                pass_word.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                arrow.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                pg.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                time_text.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

In else part, I want to hide the username field, password field, image arrow and pg is progress bar, those have to be hidden. After the for loop only it should be displayed, but when I run this code the invisible not working, those are always visible. But in first if part,that's work perfectly according to the code.

Please help, In advance thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that you want views to become invisible immediately, but that doesn't work this way, normally they become invisible in the next rendering cycle, but you don't give a system a chance to redraw views, because your main thread is busy with

```
            for(int time = 10 ; time>0 ; time--)
            {
                for(int m = 0 ; m < 1000 ; m++)
                {
                    time_text.setText("00 : 00 : "+time);
                }
            }
```

and then you are switching visibility back to

```
            user_name.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            pass_word.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            arrow.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

so it remaines visible

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem and as @Desert said, it should be done at a different rendering cycle.
To do it you can add a Handler with postDelay, that worked for me.

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        // Turn view visible/invisible
                    }
                }, 500); // Change the time for as little as long it works
```